# Rename asset file upon upload?

Tags: assets

Is there any way to rename files upon there upload to an assets field?

I know I can hit the options of the file and rename manually, but was wondering if there was a way to do this automatically? i.e. renamed based on the entry ID.

Answer (score 1):

Craft has the ability to dynamically add subfolder paths to Assets when you are creating the Asset field in the control panel.

Tags like {slug} and {author.username} are some of the available options for creating the directories.

I know it has been brought up before and they have acknowledged the possibility. So who knows, maybe we will see it in 2.2?

For now, if organization is a concern I recommend using subfolders to keep it clean.

[image: asset field options]

Comment: Yes, I've set dynamic folder locations which is really useful. It's probably just the OCD side in me, but my files (images) will come from a wide range of sources, from different users etc, so I'd rather the files have consistent naming.

Comment: Agreed, I am the same way and was one who asked this very question. I don't know what the have planned for 2.2 but I have a "feeling" a lot of great things for assets will be coming out with it ;)

Comment: Here's hoping! I'd love to (for example) rename the files with the kind of flexibility there is in setting upload location. Fingers crossed. :)

Comment: These guys always have a few tricks up their sleeves... I'm sure it will be another great release - on both developer and feature fronts.